# The LINQ expression 'DbSet<Bank>().OrderBy(b => new BankViewModel{ }.Id)' could not be translated

Tags: .net, .net-core, odata, automapper

dotnet core6:
when add to list :(var list = _bankService.GetAll();) , its ok , but i don't want fetch all data , then filter it (odata)

my controller:

```
 public class BankOdataController : ODataController
{
    private readonly IBankService _bankService;
    public BankOdataController(IBankService bankService)
    {

        _bankService = bankService;
    }

    [EnableQuery]
    
    public ActionResult<BankViewModel> Get()
    {
        var list = _bankService.GetAll();
        return Ok(list);
    }
}
```

bank service intefrace :

```
   public interface IBankService : IDisposable
{
    IQueryable<BankViewModel> GetAll();

   
}
```

bank Service:

```
public class BankService : IBankService
{
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;
    private readonly IEventStoreRepository _eventStoreRepository;
    private readonly IBankRepository _bankRepository;
    private readonly IMediatorHandler _mediator;

    public BankService(IMapper mapper,
                             IBankRepository bankRepository,
                             IMediatorHandler mediator,
                             IEventStoreRepository eventStoreRepository)
    {
        _mapper = mapper;
        _bankRepository = bankRepository;
        _mediator = mediator;
        _eventStoreRepository = eventStoreRepository;
    }

 

    public IQueryable<BankViewModel> GetAll()
    {
        var banks =  _bankRepository.GetAll();
        return banks.ProjectTo<BankViewModel>(_mapper.ConfigurationProvider);
    }

   
    public void Dispose()
    {
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
}
```

IBank Repository:

```
  public interface IBankRepository : IRepository<Bank>
{
   IQueryable<Bank> GetAll();

}
```

Bank Repository:

```
 public class BankRepository : IBankRepository
{
    protected readonly CargoContext Db;
    protected readonly DbSet<Bank> DbSet;

    public BankRepository(CargoContext context)
    {
        Db = context;
        DbSet = Db.Set<Bank>();
    }

    public IUnitOfWork UnitOfWork => Db;

    

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Db.Dispose();
    }

    public IQueryable<Bank> GetAll()
    {
        return  DbSet.AsQueryable();
    }

}
```

AutoMapper:

```
 public class DomainToViewModelMappingProfile : Profile
{
    public DomainToViewModelMappingProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<Bank, BankViewModel>();
    }
}
```

program.cs:

```
var modelBuilder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
```

modelBuilder.EntitySet("BankOdata");

builder.Services.AddControllers().AddOData(

```
options =>
{
    options.EnableQueryFeatures(1000);
    options.AddRouteComponents("odata", modelBuilder.GetEdmModel());
}
);
```

Comment: https://localhost:7213/odata/BankOdata?$top=10

Comment: https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Extensions.OData

Comment: Do you have a sample code ready? @LucianBargaoanu

Comment: Check the repo for examples. I'm sure there are more here and elsewhere online.